# JQuery UI Dialog Positioning problem

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have been googlgling around and it seems I don't get any answer :/

I'd like to know how can I make sure that the dialog title will "stick" to the top of the document even if I've scrolled down in the main page?

I tried the option "position" top, bottom but with no luck.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Hi @am5a03 you can post your solution as a resposne to your own question and mark it as the correct answer. That way people will know it's solved when browser Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Alex, because by the time when I came up with the solution, it wouldn't let me to answer my own question. I just forgot to put the response later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come up with the solution:

Using the "open" event to trigger the window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight - dialogHeight);

```
$("#open").click(function (){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            open:function(){
                window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight - 850);

            },
            modal:true,
            width:850,
            height:850
        });
    });
```

This will ensure the title of the dialog will be shown at first rather than the bottom part.